# Printing Pattern in Python

Tags: python-3.x

## 1. The Problem

> Given a positive integer n. Print the pattern as shown in sample outputs.

A code has already been provided. You have to understand the logic of the code on your own and try and make changes to the code so that it gives correct output.

### 1.1 The Specifics

Input: A positive integer n, 1<= n <=9

Output: Pattern as shown in examples below

Sample input:

```
4
```

Sample output:

```
4444444

4333334

4322234

4321234

4322234

4333334

4444444
```

Sample input:

```
5
```

Sample output:

```
555555555

544444445

543333345

543222345

543212345

543222345

543333345

544444445

555555555
```

## 2. My Answer

### 2.1 My Code

```py
n=int(input())

answer=[[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t)
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)
        a.append(i)


print(answer)      
outlst = [' '.join([str(c) for c in lst]) for lst in answer]

for a in outlst:
    print(a)
```

### 2.2 My Output

```
Input: 4
```

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4

4 4 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4

4 3 2 1 2 3 4

4 4 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4

4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4

4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

### 2.3 Desired Output

```
4444444

4333334

4322234

4321234

4322234

4333334

4444444
```

Comment: SO is not a software writing service. you should mention whatever you have tried.

Comment: Do you have a question? I don't see it

Comment: I understand the problem statement, but I don't see what your question is. Do you not know how to do it? Do you think you know how to do it but run into unexpected issues? Or what is your difficulty with it?

Comment: I have ran the code i mentioned in the question, but it doesnt match the desired Output, need help to debug my code

Answer (score 1):

Your answer isn't as expected because you add the same object `t` to the `answer` list twice:

```py
answer.insert(0, t)
answer.append(t)
```

More specifically, when you assign `t = [i]*(2*i - 3)`, a new data structure is created, `[i, ..., i]`, and `t` just points to that data structure. Then you put the pointer `t` in the `answer` list twice.

In the `for a in answer` loop, when you use `a.insert(0, i)` and `a.append(i)`, you update the data structure `a` is pointing to. Since you call `insert(0, i)` and `append(i)` on both pointers that point to the same data structure, you effectively insert and append `i` to that data structure twice. That's why you end up with more digits than you need.

Instead, you could run the loop `for a in answer` for only the top half of the rows in the `answer` list (and the middle row that has was created without a pair). E.g. `for a in answer[:(len(answer)+1)/2]`.

Other things you could do:

- using literals as the arguments instead of reusing the reference, e.g. `append([i]*(2*i-3))`. The literal expression will create a new data structure every time.
- using a copy in one of the calls, e.g. `append(t.copy())`. The `copy` method creates a new list object with a "shallow" copy of the data structure.

Also, your output digits are space-separated, because you used a non-empty string in `' '.join(...)`. You should use the empty string: `''.join(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n=5
answer=[[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t.copy())
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)
        a.append(i)
answerfinal=[]
for a in answer:
    answerfinal.append(str(a).replace(' ','').replace(',','').replace(']','').replace('[',''))
for a in answerfinal:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n*2):
    for j in range(1,n*2):
        if i <= j<=n*2-i: print(n-i+1,end='')
        elif i>n and i>=j >= n*2 -i : print(i-n+1,end='')
        elif  j<=n: print(n-j+1,end="")
        else: print(j-n+1,end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input())
k = 2*n - 1

for i in range(k):
    for j in range(k):
        a = i if i<j else j
        a = a if a<k-i else k-i-1
        a = a if a<k-j else k-j-1
        print(n-a, end = '')
    print()
```